# How can I pass parameters into an Angular $resource factory?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I'm trying to use $scope.lat and $scope.lng in my $resource Venue object, so that REST communication will always be in the context of a location. I can't tell if they are being passed in under $rootScope before they are defined in HenriettaCtrl or if they are even being passed in at all:

```
henriettaApp = angular.module('henriettaApp', ["ngResource"])

henriettaApp.factory "Venue", ["$resource", "$rootScope", ($resource, $rootScope) ->
  console.log($rootScope.lat)
  console.log($rootScope.lng)
  $resource("/venuesNear/:id",{lat:$rootScope.lat,lng:$rootScope.lng,id:"@id"}, {update: {method:"PUT"}})
]

@HenriettaCtrl = ["$scope", "Venue", ($scope, Venue) ->
  saveLocation = (position) ->
    $scope.lat = position.coords.latitude
    $scope.lng = position.coords.longitude
    console.log($scope.lat)
    $scope.streams = Venue.query()
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition saveLocation
]
```

Comment: Likely best to create a `service` that creates the `position` object that you can then pass to both your `Venue service` and `controller` as a dependency

Answer (score 0):

$rootScope will propagate down to $scope, but properties set on $scope will not propagate up to $rootScope.

You may need to use events to get the result you want, like the accepted answer to this question: [AngularJS multiple uses of Controller and rootScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180293/angularjs-multiple-uses-of-controller-and-rootscope)