# Service injection into controller with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have written a service in AngularJS, but I can't get it to work with the angular-seed way of doing things.

The controller code is as follows:

```
/*function PhotoCtrl($scope, Photo) {
    $scope.photos = Photo.query();
}*/

angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
    controller('PhotoCtrl', [function($scope,Photo) {
    $scope.photos = Photo.query();
}])
.controller('MyCtrl2', [function() {

}]);
```

Note that the commented out section works fine, but I would like to handle it somewhat like the (recommended) second way.

The error I get is that Photo is undefined, so my guess would be my method of passing (injecting) it is wrong, but I can't find out how to do it correctly

Comment: As far as I know the first method is just fine, I believe that's what's shown in the official tutorial for example. Do you have any sources that indicate otherwise?

Comment: "NOTE: Many of the examples in the documentation show the creation of functions in the global scope. This is only for demonstration purposes ......." from http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller seems to say so. Don't get me wrong, I think the first is easier to read but I understand that the name spacing might be better

Comment: If you remove wrapping square braces around controller function definition `[function($scope,Photo) {}]` you'll also be fine, but don't do it if you plan to minify your code. More about [dependencies injection in angular here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: @Maarten Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. Guess I'll have to rewrite my application :)

Comment: @KGChristensen glad to be of help ;-)

Comment: @DmitryEvseev right, I read that somewhere indeed, thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to define the `Photo` service:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .service('Photo', ['$log', function ($log) {

        return {
            query: function() {
                // the query code here.
            }
        };

    }])
    .controller('PhotoCtrl', ['$scope', 'Photo', function ($scope, Photo) {
        $scope.photos = Photo.query();
    }])
    .controller('MyCtrl2', [function() {

    }]);
```

A couple of references:

- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module
- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$provide#service

In the above sample code I used parameters aliasing, which I suggest in order to avoid issues when minifying your code.

See also an example here:
[AngularJS multiple uses of Controller and rootScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180293/angularjs-multiple-uses-of-controller-and-rootscope/13181133#13181133)

And a Plunker here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Bzjruq

Comment: I had defined the service, but your answer fixed it because you gave the right syntax for the controller line, I didn't know I had to pass scope and Photo in there like that, compare it to my example to see my problem

Comment: Note that you must also

Comment: Isn't this the `factory` syntax, not the `service` syntax? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory/13763886#13763886 (Your 3rd edit version looks like the `service` syntax.)

Comment: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html