# AngularJS - Use Service with Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller

I have written a service in AngularJS, but I don't use the service in my controller.

Service.js

```
var appService = angular.module("appService", []);
appService.service("bddService", function() {

    var bdds = bdd;

    this.getBdds = function(){
        return bdds;
    };

    var bdd = [{
        id : 1,
        nom : "Activité commercial",
        desc : "Information de l'activité commercial de l'entreprise Bou."
    }];
});
```

Controller.js

```
(function(){
    var accueilCtrl = angular.module("accueilCtrl", ['appService']);

    accueilCtrl.controller('accueilCtrl', ['$scope', 'bddService', function($scope, bddService){

        $scope.bdds = bddService.getBdds(); // No error, but no data

    }]);
})();
```

There are two files, if I put the code in the same file it works ([Service injection into controller with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876748/service-injection-into-controller-with-angularjs)). The console doesn't display errors.

Comment: Let's see how you are loading your js in your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var bdds = bdd;

this.getBdds = function(){
    return bdds;
};

var bdd = [{
    id : 1,
    nom : "Activité commercial",
    desc : "Information de l'activité commercial de l'entreprise Bou."
}];
```

This would become as below, becuase of variable hoisting concept in javascript

```
var bdd;
var bdds;
bdds = bdd;              // makes bdds undfined

this.getBdds = function(){
    return bdds;
};

bdd = [{
    id : 1,
    nom : "Activité commercial",
    desc : "Information de l'activité commercial de l'entreprise Bou."
}];
```

So do this way

```
var bdd = [{
    id : 1,
    nom : "Activité commercial",
    desc : "Information de l'activité commercial de l'entreprise Bou."
}];
var bdds = bdd;

this.getBdds = function(){
    return bdds;
};
```