# How to call a directive inside a service in template attribute in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

**Below is the directive code and service code. How to call a directive inside the service.And how to call dynamic templates**

Directive Code

```
angular.module('TestModule').directive('mymodalwindow', function () {
    return {        
        restrict: 'E',       

        template: '<div class="modal-header">' +
    '<h3>{{modalOptions.headerText}}</h3>' +
'</div>' +       
    };
});
```

Service Code

```
angular.module('TestModule').service('modalService', ['$modal',
    function ($modal) {
        var modalDefaults = {
            backdrop: true,
            keyboard: true,
            modalFade: true,
            template://How to call the above define directive here?? 1 way is <mymodalwindow></mymodalwindow> But how to pass the directives instead of giving fixed directive name

        };}
        ]);
```

Comment: Why do you need to call a directive from service?. You can inject a service into directive but not directive into service

Comment: I need to invoke the modalService from controller method, which will pop up the dialog modal. and need to replace the template of service with some other template.

Comment: Inject service into controller. See how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876748/service-injection-into-controller-with-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Takes the template outside the directive:

```
angular.module('TestModule').directive('mymodalwindow', function () {
    return { 
        restrict: 'E',
        templateURL: 'app/template/myTemplate.html'
    };
});
```

MyTemplate.html:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3>{{modalOptions.headerText}}</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the exact same situation -- needing a modal dialog service, and wanting to do it in a more Angular way than having a service injecting into the DOM.

Best approach I can find is to have the modal service create its own controller, as outlined in [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-angularjs-modal-service).