# Ionic back button not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hello I am having a problem with the back button in my project. One of the views is a newsfeed, when i click a news item to see the full content I go to the respective view. In this view i display the full content of the news and a back button.

This is the router config for this 2 views :

```
  $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: "/app",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "templates/menu/html/menu.html",
            controller: 'menuCtrl'
        }) //root

        .state('app.news-full-list', {
            url: "/news",
            params:{
               isAnimated:true
            },
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/cholnews/news_full.html",
                    controller: 'newsCtrl'
                }
            }
        })  // news feed

        .state('app.details', {
           url: '/news_details', 
           views: {    

           'menuContent': {

            templateUrl: 'templates/cholnews/news_details.html',
            controller: 'detailsCtrl'
            }
          }  
        });  //news details
```

To display the back button in the details view i use this script as suggested in ionic page:

```
 appControllers.controller('detailsCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicHistory) {
     $scope.myGoBack = function() {
       $ionicHistory.goBack();
    };
 });
```

when I go inside details the back button is displayed but does not work when clicked.It looks like the history is empty!
Any idea how t solve this ?

Comment: can you add your entire code?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just put the myGoBack function in the detailsCtrl, you should link a button in the view to that function to perform that action

Comment: yes i have done that but when i click it nothing happens

Comment: Ok, maybe you should post entire code, have you injected the services in the controller function with $inject? otherwise you can look at this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876748/service-injection-into-controller-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

as you have mentioned : `app.news-full-list` state  contain list..whose root view is "app". and when u click on any item,it opens `app.details` details, whose root view is also app.these makes change in view history.

so,just try this:

```
.state('app.news-full-list.details', {
       url: '/news_details', 
       views: {    

       'menuContent': {

        templateUrl: 'templates/cholnews/news_details.html',
        controller: 'detailsCtrl'
        }
      }  
    });
```

now, `app.news-full-list.details` shows that details have `news-full-list` is root view.

hope this helps you.!